# How to integrate mobile app with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on a mini e-commerce mobile app for a pharmacy. What I need is:

1. Register through the mobile app and using the Wordpress registration
   utility. The registration process will include sending the profile
   avatar and optionally an insurance identity image as a base 64
   encoded from the mobile app. The images should be converted, stored
   on an wp-content/upload folder, and their URL stored as user meta.
2. Login using the Wordpress credentials.
3. Insert/Update/Delete/View a product with its data.
4. Insert/Update/Delete/View a shopping cart (per user).
5. Insert/Update/Delete/View all orders (all and per user).

I am very new to Wordpress. I have to use Wordpress as there is already a Wordpress site for the pharmacy and we need to make something to plug it in with the existed website easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found those plugins which helped me getting most of the job done [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api), [JSON API Auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/), [JSON API User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/), and [CoCart](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart-rest-api-for-woocommerce/). Also I had to turn on the REST API at **WooCommerce**-> **Settings**-> **Advanced** tab